# Who picks up Street Fighter x Tekken easier a Street Fighter veteran or a Tekken veteran?

Tags: street-fighter-x-tekken

As Street Fighter x Tekken is a crossup game and has elements from both game series for whom is it easier to learn the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the game has some elements from the Tekken series, it was made by Capcom, and is much more alike the Street Fighter games than the Tekken games. There is no 3D movement, in example. The biggest Tekken element in the game (aside from the characters) is the combo system that favors juggling.

A Namco game, [Tekken X Street Fighter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekken_X_Street_Fighter), is in production with no release date announced, and it is expected that it follows the Tekken elements more closely.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I have played the game I can say for sure that a Street Fighter veteran is more likely to pickup the game faster.

The reasons are:

- The engine is very similar to Street Fighter 4. It accepts the same shortcuts.
- Many combos require links, sometimes 1 frame links
- Plinking, double tapping etc. work and make the game easier
- Tag team is new, but not that hard to understand